# Bigquery - Export multiple csv files from Storage bucket to local folder (C drive)

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

What I am trying to achieve:
Copy data from a query/view in to a csv files and then concatenate it and convert to a .hyper file for Tableau.

Step 1:
I am using the EXPORT command to copy data from a view in to csv file/s. As the view is huge ( 4million + records) it dumps 250+ files in to the Storage Bucket.

Export Command Used:

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://test/*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT * FROM `xa.dev.project.DATASET.VIEW`
```

Can I dump the csv files to a local folder instead of a bucket directly? so that I can read and concatenate them outside (Python/Pandas) and then convert to .hyper file?

Step 2:

I have tried the below to copy files from bucket to local but its not responding

```
gsutil -m cp –r gs://test_bucket/folder1/*.csv "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Test\"
```

Result: No response or error

Step3: Concatenate csv files using Pandas and create a .hyper file using Pantab

Is there a faster or better way to achieve this?

Comment: In BigQuery export command the URI should be a GCS location- you define the bucket, the folder and the file. For instances, in your case, you have specified bucket name as test ('gs://test/*.csv'), but when you are copying the contents of the bucket to local, your source location is gs://test_bucket/folder1/*.csv. The bucket name in both the commands are different and hence the error. You are exporting BigQuery data in csv format to GCS bucket, that very bucket's data should be copied to local. Try : gsutil -m cp –r gs://test/*.csv "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Test\"

Comment: How many Gb of data do you export?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere   approx 11Gb - 254 csv files to process

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I managed to run it using "gsutil -m cp gs://pt_customer_data/0*.csv ." (note the . ) its saving files on local  --> not sure how to access or change that directory..as it says not enough space.

Comment: With windows, I don't know if you can use the / or if you have to use the double \\. Have a try!